# What is the minimum resolution to view iPad simulator (portrait) without scrollbars on 100% zoom

Tags: ios, ios4, screen-resolution, ios-simulator

I bought a new 23" monitor with max. resolution of 1920x1080, but I still can't see fullscreen of the apps I develop in portrait mode.

I was wondering what is the minimum resolution required to view the iPad simulator in portrait without scrollbars. Any suggestion on video-recording the functionality of the app I develop for demo. Is there any app that can capture complete screen of the active window.

I'm aware of *copy screen* to capture complete screenshot in simulator, but I'm looking for recording a video demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iPad2, they can output video to a monitor.  You can capture it there.

Comment: Thanks bshirley. Unlucky me I only have original iPad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction, I guess using https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager to mirror the iPad simulator output to VGA (From simulator menu Hardware->Tvout -> 1024x768) and capture the video is feasible.

Comment: But I would love to know the resolution required to display complete iPad simulator (in 100% zoom) - I made mistake by combining 2 question.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad screen itself is 1024 pixels high in portrait mode. With the simulated iPad bezel, it's 1100 pixels high. So if you want to fit the whole thing on your screen with a bit of room for the menu bar and stuff, you're probably looking at 1280-ish vertical.